# Maximum profit earned in Interval

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We have to rent our car to customers. We have a list whose each element represent the time at which car will be given, second -> the time at which car will be returned and third -> the profit earned at that lending. So i need to find out the maximum profit that can be earned.

Eg:

```
( [1,2,20], [3,6,15], [2,8,25], [7,12,18], [13,31,22] )
```

The maximum profit earned is 75. [1,2] + [3,6] + [7,12] + [13,31].

We can have overlapping intervals. We need to select such case that maximizes our profit.

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping intervals"? I assume you're not talking about the time intervals

Comment: Overlapping intervals in given example are [1,2] and [2,8] , [2,8] and [3,6]

Comment: Ah, the _input_ can have overlapping time intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only one car, then the problem we are solving in [Weighted Interval Scheduling](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse521/13wi/slides/06dp-sched.pdf)

Let us assume we have intervals I<sub>0</sub> , I<sub>1</sub>, I<sub>2</sub>, ....I<sub>n-1</sub> and Interval I<sub>i</sub> is (s<sub>i</sub>,t<sub>i</sub>,p<sub>i</sub>)

Algorithm :

1. First sort the Intervals on the basis of starting points s<sub>i</sub>.
2. Create a array for Dynamic Programming, MaxProfit[i] represent the maximum profit you can make from intervals  I<sub>i</sub>,I<sub>i+1</sub>,I<sub>n-1</sub>.Initialise the last value

   ```
           MaxProfit[n-1] = profit_of_(n-1)
   ```
3. Then using DP we can find the maximum profit as :

   a. Either we can ignore the given interval, In this case our maximum profit will be the maximum profit we can gain from the remaining intervals

   ```
           MaxProfit[i+1]
   ```

   b. Or we can include this interval, In this case the maximum profit can be written as

   ```
           profit_of_i + MaxProfit[r]
   ```

   where r is the next Interval such that s<sub>r</sub> > t<sub>i</sub>
   So our overall DP becomes

   ```
           MaxProfit[i] = max{MaxProfit[i+1], profit_of_i + MaxProfit[r] }
   ```

   4. Return the value of `MaxProfit[0]`

Answer (score -1):

use something like dynamic programming.
at first sort with first element.
you have 2 rows, first show most earned if this time is used and another is for most earned if not used.
then you will put each task in the related period of time  and see in each time part it is a good choice to have it or not.

take care that  if intervals are legal we choose all of them.